# Network not found Exceptions

Tags: c#

I am trying to find a txt files over computers of a domain network.

What I have done till now:

I have the list of all computers of the domain in an array.So I am iterating each computer with its corresponding address with the help of getfile command.

Where I am stuck :

There are some computers over which I don't have access.So my search is either taking a long time to leap those exceptions or it gets struck at some point.As there are more that 500 systems so I want to increase the speed and accuracy of my program.

I am mostly getting network not found error.

Here is my code:

```
namespace ABC
{


class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> cnames=new List<string>();

        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://abc.com", "username", "password", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

        DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

        mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=computer)");

        foreach (SearchResult resEnt in mySearcher.FindAll())
        {
            string name = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Name;
            if (name.StartsWith("CN="))
                name = name.Remove(0, "CN=".Length);
            cnames.Add(name);
        }
        int cnumbers=cnames.Count;

       for (int i = 0; i < cnumbers;i++ )
        {
            string s = "\\\\" + cnames[i] + "\\ab\\cd";
            string[] dirs = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Name of Computer=" + cnames[i]);
            try
            {
                dirs = Directory.GetFiles(s);
                try
                {
                    foreach (string dir in dirs)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(dir);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try increasing the value of i by one at catch

Comment: Getfiles() method is a blocking method and will wait for an actual response before continuing.  If you put the code in an async method (like backgroundworker) you can spawn multiple threads so you don't wait for each computer to respond.